# apache-spark: How to use UDF in expr?

Tags: apache-spark

How do we use a spark UDF in expression?
I have:

```
def power3(input: Int) = input * input * input

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val power3UDF = udf(power3(_:Int):Int).withName("power3UDF")

numDF
  .select(expr("Number"), expr("power3UDF(Number) AS POWER3"))
  .show()
```

This gives error:

```
Undefined function: power3UDF. This function is neither a built-in/temporary function, nor a persistent function that is qualified as spark_catalog.default.power3udf.
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to register the function spark SQL function:

```
spark.udf.register("power3", power3(_:Int):Int)
```